# libgdx simple game is stuttering a lot

Tags: java, performance, libgdx

I just started with libgdx and so I created a simple test application where an image just moves. The problem is that even if its an extremly simple game the image is stuttering a lot while it moves. Here is the code:

```
public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter {

private Entity e;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    e = new Entity(50,50,"badlogic.jpg");
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 480, 800);
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void render () {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();

    e.setX(e.getX()+100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    e.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

The entity class:

```
public class Entity {

private Texture texture;
private Rectangle hitbox;
private float x,y;

public Entity(float x,float y,String texture){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.texture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(texture));
    this.hitbox=new Rectangle(x,y,this.texture.getWidth(),this.texture.getHeight());
}


public void draw(SpriteBatch sb){
    sb.draw(texture, x, y);
}

public boolean collidesWith(Entity e){
    return this.hitbox.overlaps(e.getHitbox());
}

public Rectangle getHitbox() {
    return hitbox;
}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

Can someone explain me why this is stuttering?

Comment: need more info on what you define as stuttering

Comment: @Barodapride Its dosent move smooth its jumps very often a few pixels

Comment: You should load the texture **only once** for the entire scope of the application, NOT in every single instance of an entity!

Comment: Well it looks like you are moving it 100 pixels per second and the resolution of the screen is only 480x800. The image should only stay on the screen for about 4 seconds. How long does it really take? Does it stutter just once or repeatedly? What happens if you remove the 100 multiplier in e.setX()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDeltaTime()` is smoothed out over multiple frames so if a average frame takes `.016 seconds` and suddenly there is a frame taking `.030 seconds` then `getDeltaTime()` will just return `.016`. So in reality the game has progressed `.030` seconds but you multiply your movement by `.016`.

`getRawDeltaTime()` gives you the real time passed since last frame. Try to use this as you multiplier. Otherwise try to log both and see if there are differences.

The benefit of using the smoothed `getDeltaTime()` is when frame drops happen the game will be still playable. While with `getRawDeltaTime()` if there would suddenly a second pass for the next frame then your velocity would get multiplied by 1 instead of `.016` and could immediately go of screen or miss collision detection.